# How to use group by with conditions different for each group

Tags: sql, sas

[image]

There are two tables. One is the table i want to group, and one contains the conditions for each group.

The result I want is the same as df3 table in the image I uploaded.

is it possible to do this without using proc iml??

Comment: What is your `logic` to get `df3` from `df2` and `df1`?

Comment: df1 contains all the days that each ID went to the hospital. At df2, the day each ID was operated is entered. In other words, I want to see only the data before each ID is operated on. How can i do this with sas?

Comment: Your output seems to be out of sync with your logic you just explained. Are you sure df1 is all the days the ID went to the hospital? Or is it the day the ID was operated?

Comment: sorry. df1 is the day each ID was operated and df2 is all the days each ID went to the hospital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using join:

```
select df2.id, df2.date from df2 inner join df1
on df2.id=df1.id and df2.date<df1.date
```